# Reading from a combo box to select SMS carriers

Tags: combobox, vb6

I am trying to write some vb6 code to allow the user to select their carrier and have the program concatenate their smart phone number(taken from tctCell) with the carriers SMS email to get "1234567890@vtext.com"
Using a combo box, I only will have 3-4 carriers to select from and a stack of one line if/then statements in lieu of select case will be used for now.
My problem is that I get "Argument not Optional" on the nMatch line. Also is my concatenation correct? I have changed ItemData values to 1,2,3,4.

Here is my code with one option:

```
Private Sub cmbCarriers_Click() 'Look up carriers from combo box
nMatch = cmbCarriers.ItemData
If nMatch = 1 Then txtSMS = txtCell.Text & "vtext.com"
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I ran a test and it looks like my concatenation works. Note that I forgot "@".

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the compile error because `ItemData` requires an index. Your code should look like this:

```
Private Sub cmbCarriers_Click() 'Look up carriers from combo box
nMatch = cmbCarriers.ItemData(cmbCarriers.ListIndex)
If nMatch = 1 Then txtSMS = txtCell.Text & "vtext.com"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Doug: No problem.  If it helped, make sure to [mark the question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).